# How to update some components of my JSP page using JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, refresh

I have a Jsp page and I want automaticly update one of the form on it using Js. Can somebody suggest something 
Thanks)

Comment: what do you mean by "automaticly update one of the form"? if there's some text that changes inside the form then i would recommend ajax push...

Comment: -1: The question is not detailed enough. Please provide some code & what you have tried so far. Please provide some detail description of what you need to change and when you need to change like onClick of some link or button you need to change the text or fields or CSS? Will the change come from server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically update the elements of the form using basic JavaScript, if thats what you are looking for. Here are some dirty examples:

Eg.
If the id of your form is `myForm`, you can use

```
document.forms["myform"].action = "somepage"; //to change the action
var elem1 = document.getElementById("elementID")` //to get an element 
var elem2 = document.forms["myform"].element //other way to get an element 
childElement = document.createElement("option"); //to create a new element 
myform.appendChild(childElement); //to append some child-element to the form
```

etc. The values/attributes/styles can be changed for the elements too using simple JavaScript. Any JavaScript tutorial on the internet should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the jQuery library (http://jquery.com/), that will allow you to manipulate HTML elements on the page, including the form element and it's children to automatically update them however you please :)

Comment: You're right, my mistake.
I tend to rely on jQuery since I've been using it for what seems like forever, but if you can get away without coupling your web application to a Javascript library, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

For an update from server side i.e Data from database or some other `file on server` use `ajax`

Now it depends on you to go for `javascript` or `jquery` to make this work.

Google this you can find good solutions.